# The following error occurs sometimes on smack 4.2 in android. I have updated the beta but its occuring again, can anyone have any solution for this

Tags: android, exception, xmpp, smack

org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.drainWriterQueueToUnacknowledgedStanzas

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Queue full
       at java.util.AbstractQueue.add(AbstractQueue.java:69)
       at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.add(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:266)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.drainWriterQueueToUnacknowledgedStanzas(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1507)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketWriter.init(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1286)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.initConnection(XMPPTCPConnection.java:649)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.connectInternal(XMPPTCPConnection.java:892)
       at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.connect(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:378)
       at unioapp.com.unio.xmpp.XMPPClient$10.doInBackground(XMPPClient.java:387)
       at unioapp.com.unio.xmpp.XMPPClient$10.doInBackground(XMPPClient.java:379)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```